# Different text column shading in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, column

I'm trying to shade columns in different colors but just can't make it.

It's either that last line of one column is part of the next paragraph, so it picks up the color of the next column:

[image]

Or it's empty first line of the next paragraph, that picks up color from previous:

[image]

Comment: In ordinary Word work, I trouble to insert one or two extra blank lines to prevent paragraphs breaking over a page break. That works well for me.

Comment: There are no page break here. All is on the same page.